# JSHINT: is there a way in to ignore camelCase only property and enforce it on variable and function

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

Hi I would like to ignore camel case inside of property but not on variables and functions.

for ex'

```
function getAllUser
{
var userName = 'bla'
var userObj = { 
first_name: 'adsf'

}
```

right now I'm using:

```
function getAllUser
{
var userName = 'bla'
var userObj = { 
/*jshint camelcase: false */
first_name: 'adsf'
}
```

my .jshintrc set to

```
{
  "asi": false,
  "bitwise": true,
  "boss": false,
  "browser": true,
  "camelcase": true,
 ...
}
```

** I dont want to use /*jshint camelcase: false */ every time I create an object or use schemas
I was hoping I could do something like that: "camelcase: ["functions","variables"]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a `.jshintrc` file in a root folder of your project where you can set all the jshint options.

Your IDE will likely understand it as well as your jshint task.

The `/myProject/.jshintrc` file:

```
{
   "camelcase": false
}
```

Note, that you can have multiple `.jshintrc` files in your folder hierarchy (so you can use different settings for tests for example).